# How to use spark connect with Kubernetes cluster

Tags: apache-spark, kubernetes, pyspark

I'm currently trying to setup spark connect on kubernetes. I'm just wondering if anyone has done this. I'm trying to figure out if I need to setup a stand alone spark cluster on kubernetes for the spark connect service using my own helm chart or if I can use the kubernetes master as the spark master for spark connect service and it will handle the creation of the executors for the cluster.

I have tried running spark connect locally with my own stand alone cluster and it works correctly, but I can't figure out how to configure spark connect with kubernetes. Can I use the kubernetes master URI?

If I try doing `./pyspark --remote "sc://kubernetes-master"` the shell launches, but just hangs if I try to read data and nothing is happening on the kubernetes cluster in terms of pods being generated.

Answer (score 0):

I stumbled on this as well. It's actually straightforward.

You have to start the server like this ([source](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/0a94e7c7b9a83ecfbca59f5b93532453f462500c/connector/connect/server/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/connect/SimpleSparkConnectService.scala#L33)):

```
bin/spark-submit --class org.apache.spark.sql.connect.SimpleSparkConnectService
```

If you want to use it on Kubernetes ([leveraging Spark-Submit](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/running-on-kubernetes.html)) you'll have to start it like this:

```
${SPARK_HOME}/bin/spark-submit \
    --master k8s://$KUBERNETES_SERVER \
    --deploy-mode cluster \
... ADDITIONAL spark config ... \
    --conf spark.kubernetes.container.image=$IMAGE \
    --class org.apache.spark.sql.connect.SimpleSparkConnectService \
    local:///opt/spark/jars/spark-connect_2.12-3.5.0.jar
```

Just make sure that you pass `spark-connect_2.12-$SPARK_VERSION.jar` as target jar to the cluster. I put it into the image since I don't want to create unnecessary downloads on the maven repositores.

If you want to use connect, you'll have to do a port-forward to your local machine.

`kubectl port-forward NAME_OF_THE_DRIVER 15002`

From that point on you can use `pyspark --remote 'sc://localhost'`.